What simple gross-motor technique could I do from here?
In a self-defense situation against a bigger, stronger man that is intent on killing or gravely injure the defender, what could the next move be from the picture below (the attacker would be the man on the ground) that would end the encounter so that the defender can safely walk away, considering there is only one attacker?


You can:

Break the arm by maintaining a hold near the wrist and kicking/stomping below the elbow.
Kick/stomp them in the head.

I would expect if you need to do this you would run, not walk away.

Since breaking the arm would involve footwork and wrist manipulation in order to work reliably (locking the joints first), the only real gross-motor move you got from this position is attacking the head.
Since and as long as they got their head down, a stomp will prove more effective. This may take too long and be a gamble since the attacker still got some posture, though. A kick from where the defender stands has a bad angle to do real damage, most promising would be a football kick with the left to the side of the head, pulling the arm in to opposite direction if possible.
One could, as an alternative, drag them across the surface with both hands for like 3-5 feet fast and attack either arm or head afterwards as well. This would make intricate footwork unnecessary. And, depending on how coarse the surface is, will occupy the attacker since they are not in as bad a position as it may seem there. The grip on the wrist cannot possibly hold if they pull the arm close and they are not flat on their belly, thus may use the combined strength of their torso and limbs still.
If you want to break the arm, grabbing near the elbow with the free hand and breaking the lower arm like you'd break a twig across the knee is much more reliable and easier than some other techniques that need more training in order to work, since a free elbow joint can be ignored there.

Is breaking a lower arm on the knee really a sound technique?  It sounds a bit counterintuitive.  You would not get much leverage and I would have thought that joints are easier to break than bones in general.

@HuwEvans It is an easy, intuitive technique where you can use a lot of big muscles against two relatively thin bones that do not withstand forces from the side well. While attacking the elbow joint makes sense from a biomechanical point of view (leverage, structural integrity), it is much harder to achieve from a technical point of view (locking the joint first, applying torque and having to apply force in exactly the correct angle). Thus, speaking of gross-motor techniques, it makes sense. And is taught in military context.

At close range like this, I am a fan of stomping my heel down on things. In this case I would consider stomping my right heel down on the back of the attacker's left hand. And to be clear, this should be a full-weight stomp, not just stamping your foot down on the hand. Stomp, pivot on that heel, and run. You could also stomp the head, but be aware that there is very little space for the attacker's head and neck to absorb the impact, so he is going to take more-or-less the full impact, sandwiched between your foot and the ground, which could do a tremendous amount of damage. That might be warranted, or it might not.
In Pencak Silat, we do a lot of dropping our weight onto the opponent (typically the extremities), so you could also come forward with the right leg and drop your weight with your shin down on the attacker's upper right arm while pulling up on the attackers right wrist. You will take out the elbow and/or shoulder, still affording you the opportunity to let go and run.

Ok. That makes sense. Thanks.

It's a little hard to answer this based on a static picture. Is the attacker on the ground still falling down towards the floor? Or have they already started to get up? Which way is the defenders weight moving? The defender has a very wide base to the feet, which will make any kind of leg technique longer to implement, and the grip on the arm is near the elbow which will reduce the leverage available.
If I am the defender in this situation, and assuming the attacker is still moving towards the floor, I am simply going to lift a foot and drop/drive my knee into the back of the head. I will maintain the grip on the arm, and if I can lift it up sharply after the knee drop I may be able to wreck the elbow or dislocate the shoulder.
If the defender is starting to get up/push away from the floor, I am stepping back and yanking the arm to break their balance, and then using my planned attack above.
Once that is done I would see if I can disengage and run or if more needs to be done.
